# Mail Sending Error to Gmail

Tags: exchange-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Mail server in windows server 2012r2 and exchange server 2013.
When I sending mail in google it is rejected and send me a error like

```
mx.google.com rejected your message to the following email addresses:
```

sanjoy.gmail (s4sanjoy@gmail.com)
mx.google.com gave this error:
[2002:7794:119::7794:119] Our system has detected that this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and authentication. Please review https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more information. ak10si19559865pad.195 - gsmtp 
Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept email from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing delivery.

Anyone can help me how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup SPF/DKIM and PTR records that use IPv6 addressing because you connect to Google mailservers using IPv6. You can disable IPv6 and use IPv4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx if you already have those records.
Otherwise you would need to create records in IPv6 format.

Example:

> v=spf1 a mx ip4:1.1.1.1 ip6:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX ~all